# How to read data in type 'integer' from file?

Tags: java, file, input, stream, integer

When i use  Character.getNumericValue(c) it understand digits from rangs 0-9. But in the file i have numbers such as: 20, 60, 999 etc
How I can to get the number from the file.

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\input.txt")) {

        int c;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {

            int digit = Character.getNumericValue(c);

        }
    }

    catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Does your file contain only numeric characters?

Comment: yes , only numeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `BufferedReader` to wrap `FileReader` (decorator pattern)
2. Use `bufferedReader.readLine()` to read lines (in a loop)
3. Use `String#split("\\s+")` to split data based on whitespaces.
4. Use `Integer.parseInt()` to parse each split value (step-3) as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc  = new Scanner(new File("D:\input.txt"));
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
  int n = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: Юлія Нечипорук Welcome. Consider accepting an answer if solve your problem. I will help others if they face similar problem.